# Summing Multiple Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

I want to build a scoring app for the submission which contestant submitted. There will be several judges which can input the score for the contestant. Here is the score model:

```
class Score < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :submission_id, presence: true
  validates :score1, presence: true
  validates :score2, presence: true
  validates :score3, presence: true
end
```

The score will appear in the score summary page as this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <p><strong>Score 1:</strong></p>
  </div>
 <% @submission.scores.each do |score| %>
  <div class="col-md-1">
    <%= score.score1 %>
  </div>
 <% end %>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <p><strong>Score 2:</strong></p>
  </div>
 <% @submission.scores.each do |score| %>
  <div class="col-md-1">
    <%= score.score2 %>
  </div>
 <% end %>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <p><strong>Score 3:</strong></p>
  </div>
 <% @submission.scores.each do |score| %>
  <div class="col-md-1">
    <%= score.score3 %>
  </div>
 <% end %>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <p><strong>Total Score:</strong></p>
  </div>
 <% @submission.scores.each do |score| %>
  <div class="col-md-1">
    <strong><%= ((0.25 * score.score1) + (0.25 * score.score2) + (0.50 * score.score3)) %></strong>
  </div>
 <% end %>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <p><strong>FINAL SCORE:</strong></p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1">
    <strong><!-- Sum all of the total score above --></strong>
  </div>
</div>
```

The page will show all of the score submitted by every judges and will sum each of the judge score in the final score.

Now, I want to sum all of the final score by every judges into the total score into FINAL SCORE. How to achieve that?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you have also multiplication for scores so it you want to use it there too do it this way:

```
@submission.scores.sum('0.25 * (score1 + score2) + 0.5 * score3')
```

If no, just do use this:

```
@submission.scores.sum('score1 + score2 + score3')
```

Comment: Another question, can I sort the view based on the highest sum total score?

Comment: Yeah, i think it should work: `@submission.scores.order('0.25 * (score1 + score2) + 0.5 * score3 DESC')`

Comment: should I place it in the controller?

Comment: I i think it is the best place ;) do not keep logic in view if you don't have to.